# How do I change the default buttons in django?

Tags: html, django, model-view-controller, django-templates, django-admin

In django admin, models have default buttons, how can I change the name of these buttons?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXpkc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the template. Indeed, this template is located at `admin/submit_line.html`.

You can however override it, by just picking an app, and adding it to the template directory of that app, so if the app is named `some_app`, it is `some_app/tempates/admin/submit_line.html`, and that app should be loaded *before* the `django.contrib.admin` app, or appear in the `DIRS` of the template engine.

The template is however not very easy to manipulate: it will need to take into account permissions, making it rather complicated, the original template looks like:

> ```
> {% load i18n admin_urls %}
> <div class="submit-row">
> {% block submit-row %}
> {% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% translate 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save">{% endif %}
> {% if show_save_as_new %}<input type="submit" value="{% translate 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew">{% endif %}
> {% if show_save_and_add_another %}<input type="submit" value="{% translate 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother">{% endif %}
> {% if show_save_and_continue %}<input type="submit" value="{% if can_change %}{% translate 'Save and continue editing' %}{% else %}{% translate 'Save and view' %}{% endif %}" name="_continue">{% endif %}
> {% if show_close %}
>     {% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' as changelist_url %}
>     <a href="{% add_preserved_filters changelist_url %}" class="closelink">{% translate 'Close' %}</a>
> {% endif %}
> {% if show_delete_link and original %}
>     {% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' original.pk|admin_urlquote as delete_url %}
>     <a href="{% add_preserved_filters delete_url %}" class="deletelink">{% translate "Delete" %}</a>
> {% endif %}
> {% endblock %}
> </div>
> ```